# JAVA NullpointerException FileInputStream(File file)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, fileinputstream

I have a problem not to solve by myself.
 I'm a biginner in JAVA.

I don't know solution about this problem. But I think that I know when this problem occurs. 
  So, I aleady have solution about this problem. But I want another solution because my solution has  another problem too. I have to reduce the process time.

```
  String intDir="C:\\RNE_IN";  

 while(true) {

        File interfaceDirectory = new File(intDir);
        String[] arrayfiles = interfaceDirectory.list(new FBMFileFilter());

        for(String f : arrayfiles){

    String filename = String.format("%1$s%2$s%3$s", intDir,File.separator,f);


        File file = new File(filename);

        FileInputStream stream = null;  

         System.out.println(file.canExecute());  // true    
         System.out.println(file.canRead());     // true    
    System.out.println(file.exists());   // true    
          System.out.println(file.isFile());     // true 
          System.out.println(file.length());    // call full bytes of file 


        // I can control NPE with this Thread sleep Time.         
        Thread.sleep(1);

        // It occurs when Stream is constructed in the below.         
        stream = new FileInputStream(file);



        FBMDeviceOnlyParser onlyparser = new FBMDeviceOnlyParser(); 

         onlyparser.ParseDeviceNameOnly(stream);    

        String onlydevice = onlyparser.getDeviceName();
        String onlystepseq = onlyparser.getStepSeq();
      }
    }
```

In above snippet, I think file has no problem.
 file state is always true and file.length is full byte regardless Exception.
 But, while infinite Loop, If I copy & paste from another Directory to the intDir , "NullPointerException" occurs.

When Thread.sleep(time) is over 1000ms, NPE doesn't occur.
 I want to delete "Thread.sleep()" code because of process time.

If there are files in the intDir aleady before program start, Program has No problem (it doesn't occur NPE)

I want to check file or FileInputStream state not to occur NPE.

Thank you for your concern.

Comment: what is the stacktrace ? and which line throws NPE?

Comment: So, what is the problem you are trying to solve? Non-working code is of no use because it does not tell us what the code is meant to do. Please explain your problem in words, not in code

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Apeiron.MainEntry.main(MainEntry.java:179)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Apeiron.MainEntry.main(MainEntry.java:260)

Comment: A "while(true)" loop with a Thread.sleep to control the problem looks a bit fishy to me. Are you aware that you open a gazillion streams on that file? Do you want to poll the file or what is your intention here?

Comment: Between "Thread.sleep(1)" and "stream = new FileInputStream(file);"

Comment: I want not to occur NPE without Thread.sleep(1) code above snippet. To solve this problem I have to insert "Thread.sleep(1000) code. Then process time of my program increase. I want to solve NPE without process time increase.  Thank you!

Comment: Again, it is hard to guess your intentions, i.e. state what you want to do, not only the how. The code looks like you're polling a dir for certain files. However, polling should occur in reasonable intervals, hence the thread.sleep. If you do not want to poll, you should rethink your while(true) approach.

Comment: This code is part of the whole my code. I must treat a lot of files in infinite loop "while(true)". So, I don't want to use "Thread.sleep()" to avoid NPE. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is hard to understand, but I can tell you for a fact that it is **impossible** to get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at Apeiron.MainEntry.main(MainEntry.java:179) Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.NullPointerException at Apeiron.MainEntry.main(MainEntry.java:260)
```

if line 179 is this line:

```
stream = new FileInputStream(file);
```

One of the following must be:

- you have given us an incomplete stack trace, or
- you've told us the incorrect location of the exception, or
- you are not actually executing that code at all; e.g. you've not rebuilt the code properly after changing it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably run out of file handles sooner or later. Close the FileInputstream when you are finished with it.

Besides that, explain what you really want to do with your code (instead of driving CPU usage to the top).

Comment: Running out of file descriptors won't cause NullPointerExceptions.

Comment: Are you sure about that? At least on windows fopen will return NULL on error. I can't check FileInputStream.open() which is called by FileInputStream(File) since it's native, but I think it would be possible that null is not checked and NPE is thrown. What would you expect in this case? The JavaDoc for FileInputStream(File) only mentions FileNotFoundException and SecurityException. Both are inappropriate, so some other sort unchecked exception must be thrown.

Comment: Axel - I'm sure about this.  A Java constructor cannot return `null`.  Not ever.  It will either return a non-null object reference, or thrown an exception.  (In this case `IOException` or a subclass.)

Comment: @Stephen: No, IOException cannot be thrown in this case since it's a checked exception and it isn't declared for FileInputStream(File). And I didn't say the constructor would return null. But internally, a file descriptor is used, which is obtained from a native call and can be NULL (as in C). So we have a FileDescriptor Object that cannot be null holding a file descriptor plus a handle obtained from the system that both can be null. I think it's quite possible a NPE is thrown when trying to use either of those.

Comment: @Axel - 1) the stack trace shows the exception is thrown in MainEntry itself.  2) `FileInputStream(File)` throws `FileNotFoundException` which is a subclass of `IOException`.  The javadoc says it is thrown "if the file does not exist, is a directory rather than a regular file, *or for some other reason cannot be opened for reading*."

Comment: @Axel - and I just did a little experiment.  If you run out of file descriptors, `FileInputStream(new File("/etc/motd"))` throws `FileNotFoundException` with the message `"/etc/motd (Too many files open)"`

Comment: @Steffen: This could be implementation dependent. I tried to check it too, but it took to long on my system, so I aborted after having more than 16mio files open. I yet have to see a complete stack trace for this example, so I can't tell. But the "or for some other reason"-part convinces me.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
String intDir="C:\\RNE_IN";  
File interfaceDirectory = new File(intDir);
while(true) {
  for(File file : interfaceDirectory.listFiles(new FBMFileFilter())) {
    System.out.println(file.canExecute());  // true    
    System.out.println(file.canRead());     // true    
    System.out.println(file.exists());      // true    
    System.out.println(file.isFile());      // true 
    System.out.println(file.length());      // call full bytes of file 

    final FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
    try {
      FBMDeviceOnlyParser onlyparser = new FBMDeviceOnlyParser(); 
      onlyparser.ParseDeviceNameOnly(stream);    
      String onlydevice = onlyparser.getDeviceName();
      String onlystepseq = onlyparser.getStepSeq();
    } finally {
      stream.close();
    }
  }
}
```

I did a couple of things -- 
  1. got rid of unnecessary file name generation
  2. put a try finally to release file handle resources

BTW, my guess is that your sleep allowed finalizers to run.

Comment: @Jini, if this answer addressed your question, please accept it.